# How to use Appium to select the elements from a searchview dropdownlist?

Tags: appium

As you can see in this picture, I can't locate the Id or XPath of the details I want to click. I'm using AndroidDriver.

[image]

I had tried the following codes:

```
            AndroidElement searchView = androidDriver.FindElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"Tribology Testing\"));");
```

but I still can't get the Tribology Testing being select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot help you to come up with the correct element locator without seeing your application layout, screenshot doesn't help at all.

You can see the layout by invoking [AndroidDriver.getPageSource()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getPageSource--) function - it will print all the UI hierarchy of the current screen and you will be able to create the corresponding selector.

Another options are:

1. [Android Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor) (part of [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools))

   [image]
2. [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html) (part of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html))

   [image]
3. [XPath Feature](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/AS+-+XPath+Feature) of the [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/)

   [image]